# Microdata for creativeWork

Tags: html, microdata

Hello I am a web design student, looking to add micro data onto my website in order to keep up with the trends (doing a major over haul), however I am having no luck with it, for instance I have the itemscore for web pages on the body, however what is for "URL" as the "isBasedOnUrl" description makes it seam like you don't use that for the main navigation and cant I cant see another alternative, also what would this code be like in a schema, i really jsut cant wrap my head around it just yet, Thanks for any help this is much appreciated.

```
<body>
     <img src="logo">
     <div id="nav">
          <a href="index.php">Home</a>
     </div>
     <div id="maincont">
          <p>Some "about" text</p>
     </div>
     <div id="footer">
          <p>copyright at name</p>
     </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to use [`http://schema.org/WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage), a more specific *CreativeWork*.

This schema doesn’t define a property for the site/page navigation (apart from [breadcrumbs](http://schema.org/breadcrumb)). And why should it in the first place? Simply use HTML5’s `nav` element. But if you need to set some properties about the navigation, you can use [`http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement`](http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement): "A navigation element of the page."

For [`isBasedOnUrl`](http://schema.org/isBasedOnUrl), did you read the description? "A resource that was used in the creation of this resource."